# Koopman representation, weakly compact action, Ozawa Popa

Tags: rt.representation-theory, oa.operator-algebras, ergodic-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Given a weakly compact action (Ozawa-Popa) of a discrete group $\Gamma$ on p.m space $X$, consider the Koopman representation $\pi$ on $L^2(X)$. Compose this representation with the Calkin projection. Will the resulting representation of $\Gamma$ be weakly contained in the left regular representation of the group, perhaps under suitable conditions?

Comment: You can just add the dollar-symbols as usual in LaTex and alike and the math renders.

Comment: Could you remind us of the definition of a weakly compact action, in this setting?

Comment: Weakly compact is the generalization  of profinite action as explained in the article of Ozawa & Popa 2007

Comment: What is the title of that article? According to zbMath, there are only three articles by Ozawa-Popa, and none in 2007.